# How to use Django to manage GIS points easily?

Tags: python, django, gis, geodjango

I'm going to write a web system to add and manage the position of driver and shops. GEO searching is not required, so it would be easier to use SQLite instead of PostgreSQL.

The core question here is that is there any easy way to manage GIS points using Django admin. I know Django have GeoModelAdmin to manage maps based on MapBox, but I could not find out how to use it just to save, delete, and update these points?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is relatively easy to manage geometry data in the Django Admin, and it's all included. You can do any of the CRUD tasks relatively simply using the Geo Model manager in much the same way as any Django model or you can use the map interface you get in the admin.

From time to time I find I want to investigate my data in more detail, and then I simply connect to my PostGIS database using QGIS and have a panoply of GIS tools at my disposal.

I would *strongly* recommend using PostGIS from the start. If there is any 'mission creep' towards more geo-functionality in the future then it will save you oodles of time. It sounds like the sort of project where spatial queries might be very useful at some point.